# Transferring data from a checkedListBox in form1 to a listBox in form2 - vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have two forms (form 1 and 2).
In form 1, I have a `checkedListBox` with a number of items that are indexed (from 0 to 29).
In form 2, I have a `listBox`.
I need to pass the items that have their `checkstate` checked from the `checkedListBox` in form1 to the `listBox` in form2, probably when form2 loads.
Your suggestions would be appreciated.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        If CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i) = True Then
            Form2.ListBox1.Text = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.ToString


        End If
    Next
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...Your `CheckedListBox` controls should have the name `CheckedListBox1` on both Form1 and Form2 for the code below to work.

On your Form2 Load event, put this code...

```
 For x = 0 To Form1.CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1
     ListBox1.Items.Add(Form1.CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(x).ToString)
 Next x
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, it worked.Only changed checkedListBox1 to ListBox1 on the second line of your code.